# Xamarin forms how to start background service when device boots

Tags: xamarin, callback, xamarin.forms, boot, background-service

I read this article: http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/ . I need to fire an event every day at 6:00, so I would like to start a background service when the device boots which triggers the event on time. Is there any callback for that? (equivalent to vanilla-android broadcast receiver)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built into Forms to support you here. Background services are very platform specific and thus will require native support.

On Android I recommend to use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM). It provides a way to send data between a client and server. However, it also exposes some additional functionality that we can take advantage of (even if you aren’t using GCM as a data service for your apps), such as the ability to schedule recurring background data refreshes at a regular interval.

You will create an Android service:

```
[Service (Exported = true, Permission = "com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE")]
[IntentFilter (new [] {"com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY"})]
```

In there, arbitrary operations can be performed.
You might want to check out this [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/performing-background-data-refresh-for-android/) post for more detail.

On iOS, you'll end up using background fetch. Again, there's a blog post with all the [details](https://blog.xamarin.com/add-background-data-refresh-to-ios-apps/).